# How to limit the number of columns in a javafx vertical flowpane

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am mainly using scene builder to create the ui for my javafx application. I am currently using a vertical `FlowPane` to get it arranged the way I would like, however instead of continuing downward the way I would like it to, it continues off the right side of the window.

[image: Application image]

I have drawn red outlines to demonstrate where I would like to have the other boxes positioned. Is `FlowPane` the appropriate container to use for this? And if so, how can I get this to work?

Comment: Do you have example code for us? Or even better an MCVE? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I didn't think it would be useful to include the fxml file, but if it would help you, I can.. The question is not about a problem with my code, but about how to achieve a vertical layout with a limited number of columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this sample `Application`:

```
private static final Random rand = new Random();
private static final int max = 200;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        root.setPrefWrapLength(5000);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setHgap(10);
        root.setVgap(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50);
            rectangle.setFill(Color.rgb((int) (rand.nextDouble() * max),
                    (int) (rand.nextDouble() * max),
                    (int) (rand.nextDouble() * max)));
            root.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(root), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The line `root.setPrefWrapLength(5000);` is the important one, as [`FlowPane.setPrefWrapLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html) determines how large (in pixels) the `FlowPane` will grow.

As your `FlowPane` is `VERTICAL`, `root.setPrefWrapLength(5000);` determines that each column grows at maximum 5000 downwards. After that a new column is created.

If you want to limit the number of columns, or in other words: The maximum width of your `FlowPane` you should switch from `VERTICAL` to `HORIZONTAL` as `FlowPane.setPrefWrapLength()` will then limit the width of your pane.

Comment: I have temporarily changed it to horizontal, but I would prefer that they be staggered vertically, rather than lined up in rows.

Comment: If I need to roll my own layout I can, I just want to first make sure I can't do this with the default FlowPane